# Where to find a list of defeated master trainers?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In Pokemon Let's Go, after beating the game, Master Trainers for each Pokemon become available to battle and take their title. Is there anywhere you can see the list of the Master Trainer titles you have successfully acquired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to see which master trainer titles you have acquired.

You need to speak to one of the ladies in the Game Freak office in Celadon City. When you talk with her, she will allow you to change your master title to any of the master trainers you have defeated.